# Inconsistent response from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, hibernate

I am facing a strange problem.
I am using jquery with hibernate and mysql backend for a simple blog application. I just want to display a post as soon as it is submitted. 
But it is working intermittently and sometimes I need to refresh page 2-3 times to get the data updated.
I am monitoring MySQL database in parallel and can see that data is updated instantly.
I have tried to debug via browser and can see that the jquery response itself is inconsistent.

Here is my js:

```js
//Method to GET data

function loadUserPosts(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'services/posts?OwnerID='+loggedInUserId,
  method: 'get',
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }, 
  success: function(data) {
   console.log("Data arrived");
   for(var index in data){
    var row = "<tr><td>"+data[index].postTitle+"</td><td>"+data[index].postVote+"</td><td><button onclick='myFunction()'>Answer/View</button></td></tr>";
    $("#userTable").append(row);
   }
  }
});
 console.log("loadUserPosts - Fired request");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 loadUserPosts();
});


//Method to POST data
function addPost(){
 var title = $("#title").val();
 var owner = loggedInUserId;
 var postData = {
     postTitle: title,
     ownerID: owner
     };
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(postData);
 $.ajax({
  url: 'services/posts',
  method: 'post',
  data: jsonData,
  headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-type': 'application/json' }, 
  success: function(data) {
   console.log("Add done");
   alert("Post added");
   $("#postForm")[0].reset();
   location.reload();
  }
 });
```

```html
        <div class="docs-section" id="div_post_content"> 
  <form id="postForm">
   <label for="Question">Post a question here</label>
     <textarea  id="title" name="postTitle" class="u-full-width" placeholder="Question Title ..."></textarea>
      <input class="button-primary" type="button" value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="addPost()"></input>
    </form>
      </div>
     <div class="docs-section" id="allPosts">
        <h6><b>Recent Questions</b></h6>
     <table id=userTable></table>     
   </div>
```

I am running this locally on Tomcat 8.0.
Any suggestions?

Based on the inputs below, I have tried following but it did not help:

1. Added below in JS File

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

2. Am calling session.clear() just before firing HQL query !!

Comment: GET requests cache, is the request cached?

Comment: try setting `cache:false`, will append timestamp to url for GET requests

Comment: It seems like there is some kind of caching server side  ( hibernate/mysql )

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, have tried the same, but did not help. I have edited my post based on your inputs.